# aspx to razor convert for master layout view

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to follow an MVC example and they used the following code

```
<%= string.Format("<link href='{0}'rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'     />",
ResolveUrl("~/Content/Site.css")) %>
<%= string.Format("<link href='{0}'rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />",   
ResolveUrl("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css"))%>
```

I want to convert it to razor.

Comment: <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.min.js)">
    @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
</head>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor version

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```